# Error ZeosLib Open Query character $ in string query

Tags: sql, postgresql, zeos

When executing a query string with the $ character, example 'select id from table where fieldname = 'abc$', it is giving error , preparade statament does not exists
Zeos Lib 7.2
Postgresql 9.6

Comment: Could you show us some code where this happens? It't not the query, that piece of SQL would work fine, it's the way how this is executed in your client program.

Comment: Exactly like this friend, I do any select, when placing a common text filter with $ in one of its characters, it gives the error

Comment: object ZConnection1: TZConnection
    ControlsCodePage = cGET_ACP
    AutoEncodeStrings = True
    Properties.Strings = (
      'AutoEncodeStrings=True'
      'controls_cp=GET_ACP'
      'Undefined_Varchar_AsString_Length=2000')
    Connected = True
    HostName = '127.0.0.0'
    Port = 0
    Database = 'database'
    User = 'postgres'
    Password = 'password'
    Protocol = 'postgresql-7'
    Left = 320
    Top = 50
  end

Comment: object ZQuery1: TZQuery
    Connection = ZConnection1
    SQL.Strings = (
      'select paramname , tipo, comandosql from vw_paramrel'
      ' where paramname = ''TEXT$'''
      '    or paramname = ''TEXT$'''
      '')
    Params = <>
    Left = 435
    Top = 50
  end

Comment: Detail, I just updated zeoslib from 7.0 to 7.2, before it worked exactly as shipped.